# Doctrine ORM orm:schema-tool update does not work

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I am using doctrine ORM and am trying to [update my database structure](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/tools.html) using this command:

```
$ vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --force --dump-sql
```

However, this is what is being returned:

```
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

You are missing a "cli-config.php" or "config/cli-config.php" file in your
project, which is required to get the Doctrine Console working. You can use the
following sample as a template:

<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner;

// replace with file to your own project bootstrap
require_once 'bootstrap.php';

// replace with mechanism to retrieve EntityManager in your app
$entityManager = GetEntityManager();

return ConsoleRunner::createHelperSet($entityManager);
```

But in reality this file exists, see below:

```
$ ls -la cli-config.php 
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 135 Aug 13 20:26 cli-config.php
```

When I run the same command on my local dev machine, it works fine. Only when I try on the server, with the exact same directly structure, it fails. Any idea why?